# bundle install してもrubygemsなどの読み込みがされず、追加したいgemのインストールができない

Tags: bundler

bundle installを叩いても、追加したいgemが追加されません。
追加したいgemの種類を変更しても同様です。

bundle installを実行したあとの表示は以下のようになります。

```
$ bundle install

Using rake 12.2.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.0
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.4
Using activesupport 5.1.4
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.1
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.2
Using loofah 2.1.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using actionview 5.1.4
Using rack 2.0.3
Using rack-test 0.7.0
Using actionpack 5.1.4
Using nio4r 2.1.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.4
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 5.1.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using mime-types 3.1
Using mail 2.6.6
Using actionmailer 5.1.4
Using activemodel 5.1.4
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.4
Using public_suffix 3.0.0
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using bundler 1.16.0
Using byebug 9.1.0
Using mini_mime 0.1.4
Using xpath 2.1.0
Using capybara 2.15.4
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using childprocess 0.8.0
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 5.1.4
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using multi_json 1.12.2
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using pry 0.11.2
Using pry-byebug 3.5.0
Using yard 0.9.9
Using pry-doc 0.10.0
Using pry-rails 0.3.6
Using puma 3.10.0
Using rack-proxy 0.6.2
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.1.4
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.3
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using selenium-webdriver 3.6.0
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using web-console 3.5.1
Using webpacker 3.0.2
Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 80 gems now installed.
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

通常であれば

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
```

などが表示されるべきところに、何も出ないまま

```
Using rake 12.2.1
...
```

と始まってしまいます。

環境は、`zsh`, `Rails`です。
このようなケースに心当たりのある方、対処法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: Gemfile と Gemfile.lock (自動更新される) が、何を bundle install するべきかが書いてありますが、そこに確かに書いたパッケージが、インストールされないということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、Gemfileの方に追加したいパッケージを追加した上でbundle installしています。

Comment: ./bundle/config を見てみましたが、`BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "production"`のみ記載されていました。

Comment: 可能であれば、 Gemfile を公開していただくことは可能でしょうか。というのも、それがない限りは手元で再現もできないので。。 (何かセキュリティポリシー的にまずい、ということであればその限りでもありませんが。。)

Comment: インストールしようとしたGemは何でしょうか。なお、追加情報はコメントで返信せず質問を編集して追記してください。